# Integration using Simpson's $1/3$ rule with infinity as upper bound and $0$ as lower bound

Tags: integration, numerical-methods

I have a question where I have to integrate the function $1/(x^2+1)$ from the lower limit $0$ to upper limit infinity using Simpson's $1/3$ rule. Using the formula $n=(b-a)/h$ where $n$ is the number of elements $h$ is the step and $b$ and $a$ are upper and lower limit respectively, one of $h$ or $n$ is going to infinity hence the code won't run. What is the solution to this conundrum?

Comment: There is no partition of $[0,\infty)$ into a finite collection of intervals, where each interval has finite length.

Answer (score 4):

Here is a suggestion: write the integral as
$$
\int_0^1\frac{dx}{x^2+1}+\int_1^{\infty}\frac{dx}{x^2+1},
$$
then make the substitution $x=\frac{1}{t}$ in the second integral.

Answer (score 0):

You could also use that
$$
\frac1{1+x^2}\le\frac1{x^2},
$$
so that the remainder after integration over the finite interval $[0,K]$ is bounded by
$$
\int_K^\infty\frac1{1+x^2}dx\le\frac1K.
$$
So if you have a target accuracy, you can divide it between this remainder and the errors of the method steps.

Still, if you can re-parametrize $[K,\infty)$ to a finite interval so that the modified integrand is still a continuous (and sufficiently differentiable) function, then you get better approximations with less effort by numerically integrating also this part.